# if文のコードの複雑な記述方法について

Tags: swift, ios

初歩的な質問ですいません。if文での表現においてどのようにしたら良いかわからず質問いたします。また、説明も分かりにくいと思われます、どうかよろしくお願い致します。

```
let test = 12.0
let test2 = 340.99
var test3 = 時間で変化するような変数が入ります
```

の時に変数（test3）が340.99から突然12.0になってしまった場合はfalseで340.99から340.98...339.12....0というように0に向かって数値が減っていき12.0になった場合にtrueとしたいのですが、そのような場合はどのようにプログラムを組むのでしょうか。
通常の<、==でもなくこのような少々複雑な条件がある場合、一つ一つif分を書いていくものなのか一気に解決するような方法があるものなのかよくわからず右往左往しております。ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: コードは断片 (この変数の値が変わる) だけではなく、もう少し具体的な範囲を提示した方が回答も付きやすくなると思います。 / 変化量を判定したいなら、変化前と後の差を比較することになりそうです。

Comment: var test3が340.99から値が小さくなる方向ででは、340.98、339.12、....0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずは、許容できる変化量を決めます。
次に、直前のtest3を保存しておく変数(ex: test4)を作ります。
あとは、test3が更新されるたびに、test3とtext4の差が、許容できる変化量以下かどうかを調べます。
継続するときは、test4にtest3を代入します。継続しないときは、trueまたはfalseを返します。
全体像が見えないので全くの想像で書きますが、下記は、突然値が小さくなったらfalseを返す関数の例です。

```
function x -> Bool {
    let delta = 0.1
    var test3 = 340.99
    var test4 = test3
    while test3 > 12.0 {
        // 
        // ここに、test3を更新する処理を入れる
        //
        if test4 - test3 > delta {
            return false
        }
        test4 = test3
    }
    return true
```

Comment: すいません、遅れました。ありがとうございます。参考にしながら色々いじって近いところまでは来ることができました、、。非常に分かり難い質問で申し訳ありません。